# LINQ Lambda to return parent items where child items ID in list of int

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a parent / child schema of matrix and location which I want to pass in a list of location Id int, then return the matrix records on the join, in SQL this returns what I need:

```
select m.* from locationmatrices lm
inner join matrices m on lm.MatrixId = m.Id
where lm.LocationId in (1, 8, 29, 68)
```

I wrote this LINQ lambda but it doesn't setup the join like I'd expect

```
var locationIdss = new List<int> { 1, 8, 29, 68 };

matrices.Where(p => p.LocationMatrices.Where(_ => locationIds.Contains(_.Id)).Any());
```

with the generated SQL being obviously wrong:

```
SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Archived], [m].[DateCreated], [m].[Description], [m].[Name]
FROM [Stock].[Matrices] AS [m]
WHERE [m].[Archived] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM [Stock].[LocationMatrices] AS [l]
WHERE [m].[Id] = [l].[MatrixId] AND [l].[Id] IN (8, 68, 29, 1))
```

I have written the LINQ in query syntax which works fine:

```
    var foo = from matrixes in _stockContext.Matrices.AsQueryable<Matrix>()
              join location in _stockContext.LocationMatrices.AsQueryable<LocationMatrix>() on matrixes.Id equals location.MatrixId
              where locationIds.Contains(location.LocationId)
              select matrixes;
```

I am just keen to know how I can write it in LINQ Lambda, for consistency in the codebase (as its all LINQ lambda) as well as for my own knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: Linq generated the `exists` as expected. You need [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-7.0). BTW, are you expecting duplicate matrices records if, for example, one matrice record joins with two locationmatrices records?

Comment: I thought may need Join but unsure of the syntax. Also should return unique matrix records only (may have been an oversight in my query) but will look to address that.

Comment: _Also should return unique matrix records only_ then your original attempt (that generates an exists query) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have setup relations correctly in the context you can try:

```cs
var lms = _stockContext.LocationMatrices
   .Where(l => locationIds.Contains(l.LocationId))
   .Include(l => l.Matrix) // assuming this exists
   .Where(l => l.Matrix != null)
   .ToList();

var result = lms
   .Select(l => l.Matrix)
   .ToList();
```

Otherwise I would argue that rewriting query in method syntax would not be that pretty and personally I would stick with the query syntax.

**UPD**

Missed that only `Matrix` data needed, so try simplified query:

```cs
var lms = _stockContext.LocationMatrices
   .Where(l => locationIds.Contains(l.LocationId))
   .Where(l => l.Matrix != null)
   .Select(l => l.Matrix)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Why `Include` here?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv so `Matrix` is filled in the results. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, missed `ToList`. Another question why first `ToList` and `Include`? ;)

Comment: That worked perfectly - thanks. Is there some refactoring needed off of the back of these comments guys?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Is there easier way to make this work correctly? `Select` will "disable" the include without `ToList`, `AsEnumerable` can be used but I left a place to use `Async` counterparts.

Comment: @GuruStron, I do not understand why query is splitted. `.Where(l => l.Matrix != null).Select(l => l.Matrix).ToList()`. No Includes are needed and `LocationMatrice` is not loaded just `Matrix`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv ohh, I missed that only Matrix data is needed for some reason thought that LocationMatrices should be present in the result too, hence the Include and "post-processing". Thank you!

Comment: many thanks guys  :)  I have now removed the .Include, also to mention I added a .Distinct as per the oversight raised by one of the other users